# Stimulate Estimote Sticker Beacon For Development

Tags: estimote, beacon

I don't have Sticker Beacon (Nearables) but I want to start development. How can I     stimulate it virtual to begin development using its SDK?

Comment: Are you developing on iOS or Android?

Answer (score 0):

I have Beacon stickers and I have same question before buying stickers.I think you can not start development without Beacon Sticker because Beacon stickers have some functionality like detect temperature and orientation.Stickers have feature like it can send data while in motion.

You can start development using Beacon with the help of estimote app and convert your phone into virtual beacon.You can not convert your phone into virtual stickers because your phone can not detect temperature and orientation.